# Is it impossible to update data without update a component in Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js

There is a template

```
<div class="wrap">
   <p v-for="item in items">
     {{ item }}
   </p>
</div>
```

There is a data

```
data: {
  items: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

Problem: after update DOM I trying to actualization data, but update a data causes to re-rendering a component.

[image]

Expected result:

[image]

Question: how to synchronisation data after update DOM?

[Live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/simati/pcazes90/)

Comment: Vue is data-driven and based on virtual Dom. Your use case will break the rules. May we know why you want to do this?

Comment: sure) my app have drag&drop with 3rd party library.

Comment: if so, you should find a way uses change data instead, like when drag one item to new position, just change the data property instead

Comment: @Sphinx, course I can cancel drop on the end dragging, but this way breaks the animation

Comment: The question should be about your drag'n'drop case. As it stands now, it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/254800) where the answer is: don't do it.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, how did you determine that the problem is in drag'n'drop if you have not seen my application?

Comment: You mentioned it yourself in the comments.

Comment: I answered for Why, see first comments

Comment: You did answer why, so we thought you have one 3rd party library will direct change Dom which may be not a Vue-friendly library. Even the goal is not DnD, but the answer for `Question: how to synchronisation data after update DOM?`, it will still be 'Don't do it'. Even you can sync the data after Dom change, Vue will re-render then may cause Dom Change, then fall in one loop.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one simple demo on the implemention of drag/drop by Vue.

1. Create one watch, it will watch `this.dragedItem`. if changed, it will re-calculate the styles which apply to the dragItems.
2. When **drag start**, get current dragging item (dragedItem=current item).
3. When **drag end**, reset dragging item (dragedItem={}),
4. When **drop**, remove item from dragItems, then push to dropItems.

In above steps, we just need to change the data, then Vue will auto render.

You can check [HTML Drag And Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API) for more details.

For the transition effects, you can check [Vue Guide: Enter/Leave Transition](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html) and [Vue Guide: State Transtion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html).

```js
app = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    dragItems: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
    dragedItem: {},
    dropItems: [],
    styles: {},
    defaultStyle: {'opacity': '', 'background-color': 'yellow'}
  },
  watch: {
    dragedItem: function () {
      this.styles = this.dragItems.reduce((pre, cur) => {
        pre[cur] = cur === this.dragedItem.item ? {'opacity': 0.5, 'background-color': 'blue'} : {'opacity': '', 'background-color': 'yellow'}
        return pre
      }, {})
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onDragStart: function (ev, item, index) {
      ev.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain',null)
      this.dragedItem = {item, index}
    },
    onDragEnd: function (ev) {
      this.dragedItem = {}
    },
    onDrop: function (ev) {
      this.dropItems.push(this.dragedItem.item)
      this.dragItems.splice(this.dragedItem.index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.dragzone {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.dragger {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.dropzone {
  width: 200px;
  height: 30px;
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="dragzone">
    <div class="dragger" draggable="true" 
    v-for="(item, index) in dragItems" :key="index"
    :style="styles[item] ? styles[item] : defaultStyle"
    @dragstart="onDragStart($event, item, index)" 
    @dragend="onDragEnd($event)"
    >
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="dropzone" @drop.prevent="onDrop($event)"
    @dragover.prevent=""
  >
    <div class="dragger" style="background-color:yellow" draggable="true" v-for="(item, index) in dropItems" :key="index">
      {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Though I like the implementation, I would move the styling to CSS, only toggling classes on the elements.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, depending on your choice. But sometimes uses styling as data will be better, check [Vue State Transition Demo](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitioning-state.html#Bringing-Designs-to-Life)

Comment: In the state transition demo, they only change calculated values to transform the elements, this is the only exception to the rule of styling in JS in my book.

Comment: Hardcoded opacity and colors should really be out of the logic.

Comment: @EmileBergeron, For most situations, I agree with you. But if I'd like to change the background-color  and opacity based on how far the users already drag (like color from #fff to #ff0, opacity from 0.5 -> 0.2), css-in-javascript will be my option. Anyway, I just want to share a demo how Data-driven works, then along with some simple styles which are data-driven also.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but DnD is not a goal of this question. For DnD + Vue I recommend https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable

Comment: @VolodymyrSymonenko It is one sample on how to implement DnD by Vue (Data Driven). Even your goal is not one DnD, but the sprit (Data Driven) is same. As you asked, you'd like to sync data with the latest Dom, but Vue work flows will be like `compile template to VNode => Update VNode (Update Data/Props etc) => Generate Dom based on VNode`, That is why some librarys like JQuery is not recommanded for Vue. Anyway, you should choose some librarys like what you mentioned (Vue Draggable), not the librarys like JQuery based.