# How to drag items between two linked timelines?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vis.js, vis.js-timeline

I have two linked timelines, so what I wanna know is there anyway to drag items between those two timelines.

The first timeline is the `Queue` and the second timeline is my `Main Timeline`. So I want to make that I can drag and drop items from `Queue` to the `Main timeline` and vice versa.

Here are my two timelines.

[image]

Main timeline options:

```
var options = {
    onMove: function (item, callback) {
      console.log('content', item)
    },
    onAdd: function (item, callback) {
      console.log(item)
      callback(item)
    },
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
    min: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
    zoomMin: 1000 * 27 * 24 * 24, // if you want to zoom more in then lower the 27
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3,
    stack: false,
    showMajorLabels: false, // hide date
    showMinorLabels: false, // hide time
    autoResize: true,
    orientation: 'top',
    editable: {
      add: true,
      updateTime: true,
      updateGroup: true,
      overrideItems: false,
      remove: true
    }
  }
  this.mainTimeline = new visTimeline.Timeline(container)
  this.mainTimeline.setOptions(options)
  this.mainTimeline.setGroups(groups)
  this.mainTimeline.setItems(items)
  this.mainTimeline.on('rangechange', function (properties) {
    self.mainProperties = properties
})
```

Queue options:

```
var options = {
    onMove: function (item, callback) {
      console.log('content', item)
    },
    start: new Date(),
    end: new Date(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 + (new Date()).valueOf()),
    min: new Date(2018, 0, 1),
    max: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
    zoomMin: 1000 * 27 * 24 * 24, // if you want to zoom more in then lower the 27
    zoomMax: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 31 * 3,
    autoResize: true,
    orientation: 'top',
    editable: false
    // editable: {
    //   add: true,
    //   updateTime: true,
    //   updateGroup: true,
    //   overrideItems: false,
    //   remove: true
    // }
  }
  this.queueTimeline = new visTimeline.Timeline(container)
  this.queueTimeline.setOptions(options)
  this.queueTimeline.setGroups(groups)
  this.queueTimeline.setItems(items)
  this.queueTimeline.on('rangechange', function (properties) {
    self.queueProperties = properties
})
```

Are there any solution for this? Thanks!

Comment: Show some code?

Comment: I just linked those two timelines. I don't have anything of the code for drag and drop. I know that in `vis.js` if I set `editable = true` then I can drag the items and drop them in the same timeline. But I wanna know if there is a solution in `vis.js` for drag and drop in linked timelines.

Comment: OK, interesting problem. I voted you back to zero.

Comment: this is one simple demo for [Vue DnD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50862803/5665870)

Comment: heh, I need the same feature, but I'm only trying to solve it

Comment: This is an old topic but did anyone find a solution?